# Javascript add method to method of a class

Tags: javascript

I have a JS class

```
function controls() {
}
```

and i am adding it a method using prototype

```
controls.prototype.treeView = function (selector) {
    var el = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        el[i].innerHTML = '<ul></ul>';
    }

    return el;
}
```

now what i want to do is add a method to this method treeView. If you have a different approach in mind please share.

EDIT: This is a solution i found which is well encapsulated

```
function controls() {

    var TreeView = function (el) {
        this.el = el;
    }

    TreeView.prototype.addNode = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.el.length; i++) {
            var tree = this.el[i].getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
            tree.innerHTML += '<li></li>';
        }
    }

    function treeView(selector) {

        var el = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            el[i].innerHTML = '<ul></ul>';
        }

        return new TreeView(el);
    }

    return {
        treeView: treeView
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by adding a method to the method? Perhaps show some code that you'd like to be able to use after adding it?

Comment: do you mean you want to add a method to `el`?

Comment: i just want to work with the method treeView like this:

treeView.addNode();

yeah that would probably mean adding a method to the el but indirectly as i don't want to attach prototype to the array directly

Comment: Instead of putting `treeView` on `controls.prototype`, you should have it as a separate constructor function so that you can make `treeView` objects. Then when you make a control, you can give it its own `treeView` object if that's what you need.

Comment: @georgi-it Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/E2g2d/ ?